# Unable to populate vector inside struct

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ so bear with me.

I made a struct that looks like this:

```
struct node{
   double startPoint;
   double endPoint;
   vector<node*> children;

   void addChild(node *aNode){
      children.push_back(aNode);
   }
   void addPoints(double start, double end){
      startPoint = start;
      endPoint = end;
   }
};
```

Down the line in my program, I have the following:

```
vector<node*> data;
....
node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->addPoints(lexical_cast<double>(numbers[0]), lexical_cast<double>(numbers[1]));
data[index]->addChild(temp);
```

where "Index" is a index of the vector data. the `lexical_cast` stuff is taking those numbers from string to doubles.

Everything works until the `addChild(temp)` line.

The terminal spit this out:

```
First-chance exception at 0x585b31ea (msvcr90d.dll) in Tree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdc1.
Unhandled exception at 0x585b31ea (msvcr90d.dll) in Tree.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdc1.
```

But I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `malloc` instead of `new` to initialize dynamic variables?

Comment: what did the debugger say?

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` allocates some space, but doesn't put anything in it. It works fine for plain-old-data structures (or trivially initializable classes), and in C that's all you have.

In C++ you have classes, like `std::vector` amongst others, which need to be properly constructed in order to establish some invariants. This is done with a straight declaration for objects with automatic storage duration, but for dynamically-allocated objects you need to use `new` instead of `malloc`.

For example,

```
std::vector<int> global;    // (1)
void foo() {
    std::vector<int> local; // (2)
    std::vector<int> *bad = malloc(sizeof(*bad));  // (3)
    std::vector<int> *good = new std::vector<int>; // (4)
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> better(new std::vector<int>); (5)
}
```

1. is fine - this global is initialized (by which I mean the constructor is called) automatically
2. is fine - this local variable is also constructed automatically, and destroyed properly as soon as `foo` exits
3. you can't use `bad` for anything, because any method you call will assume the constructor ran already, and it didn't

   - ok, you can't use `bad` for anything *without explicitly constructing it using placement new*. You shouldn't do this though, it's only appropriate where you're doing clever or tricky stuff with custom allocation.
4. this is ok (but note you have to delete it manually - `foo` has a memory leak)
5. this is better - you don't need to clean up manually

---

Now, note that your `node` class *also* has a constructor. In this case, it's automatically-generated, and does nothing but call the `vector` constructor. Still, you need it to be called, which means using `new` for dynamically allocating a `node`.

So, your program should probably look more like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> data;
...
std::unique_pre<node> temp(new node);
temp->addPoints(...);
data[index]->addChild(temp);
```

Note I'm assuming `data[index]` is valid (I see from `addChild` you know how to populate a vector already), and that the single-owner model implemented by `unique_ptr` is appropriate.

Comment: yr final assumption is incorrect, which is why his app is failing

Comment: Thanks. How can you tell the problem is the `data` vector, and not the `children` vector?

Comment: cos he showed the code to correctly setup children and push things into it (apart fro the malloc instead of new - which probably worked). He didnt show the same code for data - so i assume its not there

Comment: Unless I missed a placement new for `children`, I don't think it _is_ set up right. That vector's members are uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the code I see, you never add any nodes into the `data` array

```
data.push_back(something);
```

So accessing `data[index]` would be out of the allocated memory of the array.  It won't complain until you try to set memory in that block (via `addChild` trying to push an element into the `children` array).

Comment: this is the reason yr code is failing, all the other answers are telling you that you have other things wrong or that it could be implemented  in a more modern way. Certainty never use malloc : use new. Alos strongly recommend not to have vector of naked pointers, better to have vector of smart pointers

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend that you store a `node` instead of a `node*` in your vector so you don't have to manage the memory on your own.
2. this is C++ so you don't have to malloc the space for a node you can use new like so:
   `Node * n = new Node();`
3. New is much better because it calls the constructor and allocates space, whereas malloc just does the latter.

---

**You haven't shown much of your code, but I would restructure the node class like this.**

```
struct node{
   double startPoint;
   double endPoint;
   vector<node> children;
   node(){} //add default constrcutor    
   void addChild(node aNode){
      children.push_back(aNode);
   }
   node & operator=(const node & n) {
       startPoint = n.startPoint;
       endPoint = n.endPoint;
       return *this;
   }
   node(double start, double end): startPoint(start),endPoint(end){
   } //in c++ you have constructors which this should have been in the first place
     //constructors are used for initializing objects
};
```

1. this is better is that now you can't pass add child `nullptr` avoiding a lot of problems in your code. You also have a constructor now. Now you can add a node like this.

`node temp(start,end); data[index]=temp;`

1. You have a constructor now which `addPoints` should have been in the first place
2. I also made an assignment operator

---

> Using the style of coding where you allocate memory on the stack and don't use new is called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and is a vital technique for learning c++ and producing exception safe code, this is the main reason I advocate not storing `node*`'s